# Rules for additional commas for Text-to-speech (ChatGPT)

Tags: chatgpt, prompt-design, chatgpt-3.5

For a more natural Text to speech output, it is necessary to add additional commas so that there are micropauses and the text sounds more like a human voice.
*Grammatical commas are already in the text*. Additional commas are needed.

My text to speech engine (Microsoft Speech studio, Azure) makes perfect voiceover when I add commas to my texts manually.

I want to automate this task, for example using ChatGPT or another way. But so far it’s not working. If you have solved a similar problem, share your experience.

I'm using the free web version of *ChatGPT-3.5*. If I find a solution, I will use the API in the future.

**What I tried to do:**

**1.** I gave ChatGPT a set of my sentences (about 300), the original version and the version with additional commas, which I placed manually. I asked to find my pattern (set of rules) of how I add commas. This works well, but only once. Immediately after this ChatGPT adds commas well. But after that the second text can no longer be processed well. Apparently he “forgets” the rules he finds.

**2.** I asked ChatGPT to give me the found rules explicitly. And I added rules to each prompt, before the text. Works poorly, commas are in the wrong places as a result.

**3.** I tried to make up rules for additional commas myself. It hasn't worked out yet. There are either too few or too many commas.

**4.** I asked ChatGPT how to correctly compose a prompt for ChatGPT to place additional commas for text to speech. The essence of the answers: "...keep experimenting."

**What kind of help do I expect:**

1. Maybe someone has a ready-made prompt for this task. Or a set of rules for commas TTS for the English language.
2. Maybe there are a Python scripts (or in another language) for placing commas for tts. Or ready-made applications or services for this task.

Comment: For this you can try setting up a vector database. The database would contain the text you need to change. The prompt would contain the rules to apply and the rules would be generated by chatgpt. You would need to append the rules to your prompt and ask that chatgpt apply it to the specific text you wish to change.

Comment: Questions on this site should be specific and focused on using a generative AI tool. If you focus the question on using ChatGPT to help you place the commas, the question might be OK, but as it is currently written, "What kind of help do I expect?", the question needs to be more focused.

Comment: It's hard for me to write more focused than "I need a prompt."  ...or a set of rules for this task, from which I myself will make prompts and test the results....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to tell it to write a guide of the comma use based on the example you give it(if you have more then one example to give or try break one in more than one).Tell it that the guide must be made for a person that never had access to the previous example texts and this person reading it only it must be able to implement the same comma rules in new texts.

Something like:
"Analyse carefully the example texts and the patterns of its comma use and write a detailed guide of how comma usage is applied in it, keep in mind that the guide will be used by a person that has never seen the example texts and this person should be able to replicate the same comma pattern used that is in the original in new texts only by reading your guide.This pattern of comma use implemented on the examples is important to generate texts that generate a better transcribed audio experiences".

After you can instrunct it to transform the new text using the guide it created or to generate a prompt to transform new texts that implements the guide.

OBS1: It can be a limitation of GPT 3.5 model, some tasks it just can't do it so well, you can try the most recent free versions chatbots avaliable like Gemini, Claude or Mistral.
gemini.google.com
claude.ai
chat.mistral.ai

OBS2: You can ask the LLM to improve my example prompt as a prompt engineer if it fails before giving up on the model.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'll try this.
I was already tired of placing commas manually, and came to the conclusion that it would be better for me to write a script in Python, there are tools for analyzing sentence structure.

Another difficulty for me is that English is not my native language.

and the most amazing thing is that thousands of content creators sit and manually insert pauses into their texts before AI text to speach

 - and at the same time there is ABSOLUTELY no information about this task on the Internet. As if this problem doesn't exist...